# Gerar JSON com cabeçalho e detalhe de vários registros

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

- **`orcamento`** que guarda a informação do cabeçalho do orçamento;
- **`orcamentoItens`** que guarda os itens do orçamento;
- **`itens`** que guarda os detalhes dos itens.

<sub>(Colocarei as colunas na *query* que utilizo).</sub>

Eu consigo gerar o JSON no seguinte formato para um único orçamento:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "titular": "CARVALHO",
    "data": "2019-04-02",
    "status": "A",
    "itens": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "nome": "PRODUCT SAMPLE 2",
            "quantidade": "2",
            "preco": "127.74"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "nome": "PRODUCT SAMPLE 5",
            "quantidade": "1",
            "preco": "215.45"
        }
    ]
}
```

Para gerar esse JSON utilizo esse código:

```
$id_orcamento = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT id, titular, data, status FROM orcamentos WHERE status = 'A' and id = $id_orcamento LIMIT 1");
$orcamento=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT i.id, i.nome, oi.quantidade, oi.preco FROM orcamentoItens oi JOIN itens i ON i.id = oi.item WHERE oi.orcamento = $id_orcamento");
$itens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$orcamento['itens']=$itens;
echo json_encode($orcamento);
```

> ## Como fazer para gerar o mesmo formato de JSON para vários orçamentos de uma vez só?

<sub>Sei que posso fazer uma *query* que liste todas as informações de vários orçamentos fazendo o JOIN de todas as tabelas envolvidas (Já tenho essa *query*), porém como vai repetir as informações do cabeçalho do orçamento, não sei como fazer para gerar o JSON no formato que preciso.</sub>

Comment: Coloca todos os retornos em um array, da forma que necessitar, depois faz o json_enconde de tudo

Comment: OK, mas como fazer para por todos os itens do orçamento dentro da chave itens no array? Preciso que o JSON mantenha o formato que coloquei na pergunta, se fazer o `json_encode` da query com os `JOIN's` vai gerar vários registros com o cabeçalho repetido.

Comment: Então vamos la.... o banco quem conhece é voce, é muito mais facil você montar isso dentro de um array conforme sua necessidade .... depois de pronto você converte esse array para json. Aqui você ira encontrar um caminho para a resolução do seu problema. Não a solução dele, dificilmente alguém fará por você.

Comment: Sério? Porque que eu fiz essa pergunta aqui mesmo? Poxa cara, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Primeiro vc precisa fazer em uma query só, para otimizar

```sql
select  
    o.id, o.titular, o.data, o.status, 
    i.id, i.nome, oi.quantidade, oi.preco 
from orcamentos o
inner join orcamentoItens oi
on oi.orcamento = o.orcamento
inner join itens i on i.id = oi.item
where o.id = $id_orcamento;
```

- Depois vc da um loop no resultado, criando um array com as chaves sendo os respectivos índices, +- assim:

```php
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $toJson[$row['o.id']]['id'] = $row["id"];
        $toJson[$row['o.id']]['titular'] = $row["titular"];
        $toJson[$row['o.id']]['data'] = $row["data"];
        $toJson[$row['o.id']]['status'] = $row["status"];
        $toJson[$row['o.id']]['itens'][] = [
            "id" => $row["i.id"],
            "nome" => $row["i.nome"],
            "quantidade" => $row["oi.quantidade"],
            "preco" => $row["oi.preco"]
        ];
    }
```

- Depois só retornar o json

```php
    json_encode($toJson);
```

Abraço

Comment: Consegui gerar um JSON já bem parecido com o que preciso, basta só fazer alguns ajustes, muito obrigado Diego!

Comment: por nada, Laércio! abraço